# Why can't I use an expression to build a class name in Perl's require?

Tags: perl

Suppose the module `AAA::BBB::CCC` located in `~/modules/AAA/BBB/CCC.pm`,
and "`~/modules`" is in `@INC`, so why the following code doesn't work and lead to compile error?

```
$class = "AAA::BBB" ;
$type = "CCC";
require $class . '::' . $type ;
```

I try to use require `AAA::BBB::CCC` instead, it works . If I do need dynamically require a module by combining strings together rather than hardcode the module name directly, how should I do ?

thanks

Comment: Did you ever think to look at "perldoc -f require"? i.e. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My approach:

```
my $class = "AAA::BBB";
my $type = "CCC";

my $full_class_name = $class . '::' . $type;
( my $file_name = $full_class_name . '.pm' ) =~ s{::}{/}g;

require $file_name;

$full_class_name->test();
```

Using eval, if you're only doing "die $@ if $@" doesn't make much sense - without eval it will work just as fine.

This additional step of making file_name, and requiring $file_name instead of class makes it not required to use string based eval, which tends to be rather slow.

Of course you still can use eval if you want to provide some kind of fallback:

```
eval { require $file_name };
if ( my $error = $@ ) {
    ... do something ...
}
```

But note, that this is block-based eval, and not a string-based one.

Comment: See the part that starts with "But if you try this: ... " in http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html

Comment: @Sinan: not sure how's that relevant. My code doesn't fall in this pitfall. And the fact that they show usage of string-based eval - well - it's not my fault ;-P

Answer (score 7):

If I may restate your symptoms, I assume you mean this ***fails*** like so:

```
require "AAA::BBB" . "::" . "CCC"; # built from $class and $type;
# => Can't locate AAA::BBB::CCC in @INC (@INC contains ...
```

because it cannot find a file named `AAA::BBB::CCC`.  However, this ***succeeds***:

```
require AAA::BBB::CCC;  # note, this is _not_ quoted
```

because perl searches for a subdirectory-nested module named, in part, `AAA/BBB/CCC.pm`.

This is how `require` works.  From the documentation for [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) *`EXPR`*:

> If *EXPR* is a bareword, the require assumes a ".pm" extension
>   and replaces "::" with "/" in the filename for you, to make
>   it easy to load standard modules.

So, you must generally either convert your constructed module name to a pathname fragment (s!::!/!g appending ".pm"), or string eval your constructed module name, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 5):

From [perldoc -f require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html):

> But if you try this:

```
$class = 'Foo::Bar';
require $class; # $class is not a bareword
#or
require "Foo::Bar"; # not a bareword because of the ""
```

> The require function will look for the
>   "Foo::Bar" file in the @INC array and
>   will complain about not finding
>   "Foo::Bar" there. In this case you can
>   do:

```
eval "require $class";
```

Therefore, you can try this instead:

```
$class = "AAA::BBB";
$type = "CCC";
eval qq{ require "${class}::${type}" };
```

Comment: @depesz There is no need to downvote this answer. This is how the documentation for `require` tells you to provide a non-bareword argument to `require`.

Comment: @depesz Can you explain why you think this is a bad idea? Security? Performance?
Also, I have no problem with the down vote, except: too often (the 80 in 80/20) the questions can easily be answered with four letters: RTFM. So it's surprising to get down voted for Q(uoting)TFM.

Answer (score 1):

> suppose the module `AAA::BBB::CCC.pm` located in `~/modules/AAA/BBB/CCC.pm`

There is no such thing as `AAA::BBB::CCC.pm`. There is only `AAA/BBB/CCC.pm` and is `AAA::BBB::CCC`.

Don't confuse package names and module files.

Comment: @Manni : It's my fault, I've changed "AAA::BBB::CCC.pm" to "AAA::BBB::CCC". thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have this kludgy utility class defined in my current project:

```
package Util::RequireClass;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import'; # gives you Exporter's import() method directly
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(requireClass);

sub requireClass
{
    my $class = shift;
    eval "require $class" or do { die "Ack, can't load $class: $@" };
}

1;
```